# How to change the caret color in a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, caret

I'm creating a jTable were I can add new rows with text that can be modified, when I selected the row I want to rewrite the caret color is so light I can't see it so I don't know where I am writing. How can I change the caret color?

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is get the editor component of your cell(s) and if it's a subclass of JTextComponent, call [`JTextComponent.setCaretColor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setCaretColor(java.awt.Color)). By default, editors for a JTable are instances of JTextComponent.

Example:

```
JTable yourTable = new JTable( ) {
    public Component prepareEditor( TableCellEditor editor, int row, int column ) {
        Component c = super.prepareEditor( editor, row, column );
        if( c instanceof JTextComponent )
            ((JTextComponent) c).setCaretColor( Color.RED );
        return c;
    }
};
```